# Moodle form displays false value

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

In an `activity` `module` in `Moodle`, I had `advcheckbox`, which saved, if the user wants to have 4 seater as a car. It looked like this:

```
        $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'fourseater', get_string('fourseater', 'newmodule'));
        $mform->setDefault('fourseater', 0);
        $mform->setType('fourseater', PARAM_BOOL);
```

It all worked fine, the value was correctly saved, if you check the box, you get fourseater in the info about the workers. Then I wanted to change the form, so the user can choose between 2 and 4 seater car. A dropdown, that looks like that:

```
$caroptions = array(
                0 => get_string('selectcar', 'newmodule'),
                1 => get_string('twoseater', 'newmodule'),
                3 => get_string('fourseater', 'newmodule'),
    );
$mform->addElement('select', 'caroptions', get_string('caroptions', 'newmodule'), $caroptions);
$mform->setDefault('caroptions', 0);
```

It is correctly displayed, but in the database is saved only the `twoseater`. As I have also option to download the users records as `.xls` there is also every time saved only the `twoseater`, no mather what I choose. Here is, how the data is being extracted to `.xls`:

```
$data[] = ($workers->fourseater == "1") ? get_string('fourseater', 'newmodule') : get_string('twoseater', 'newmodule');
```

In the database, this is the field for the form (I didn't change the name of the `fourseater` to `caroptions`, as it didn't make any difference):

```
<FIELD NAME="fourseater" TYPE="int" LENGTH="1" NOTNULL="false" DEFAULT="0" SEQUENCE="false"/>
```

What I am doing wrong, that after I changed the `form` it stoped working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you still got

```
$mform->setType('fourseater', PARAM_BOOL);
```

It should be

```
$mform->setType('fourseater', PARAM_INT);
```

Also the name of the select is `caroptions` - I'm guessing it should be `fourseater`?

Comment: Yes, it was from the forgotten `PARAM_INT`. Thanks Russell!